# Python Version in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to find out the python version I am using in Databricks.

To find out I tried

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

And I got the output as **3.7.3**

However when I went to Cluster --> SparkUI --> Environment

I see that the cluster Python version is **2**.

Which version does this refer to ?

When I tried running

```
%sh python --version
```

I still get Python 3.7.3

Can there be a different python version for each worker / driver node ?

Note: I am using a setup where there is 1 worker node and 1 driver node (2 nodes in total with the same spec) and Databricks Runtime Version is 6.5 ML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** This issue has been fixed.

**For new cluster:** If you create a new cluster it will have python environment variable as 3.

**For existing clusters:** You need to add in Environment Variables tab in **Cluster Configuration** > **Advanced**, it changes in the Environmental variable.

> **PYSPARK_PYTHON=/databricks/python3/bin/python3**

[image]

---

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This is a product-bug, currently I'm working with the product team to fix the issue asap.

> The default Python version for clusters created using the UI is **Python 3**.

As part of repro, I had created Databricks Runtime Version: 6.5 ML and observed the same behaviour.

Cluster --> SparkUI --> Environment shows incorrect version.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This works in all notebooks either *gooogle colab* or *MS Azure Databricks*:

```
!python --version
```

Comment: Just ran in Databricks notebook and went fine

Comment: I had to add `%sh` to the top of the cell

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are running a cluster that is using Databricks Runtime 5.5 or below.
What you see when you run

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

is the python version referred by the PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable. The one in *Cluster --> SparkUI --> Environment* is the python version of the Ubuntu instance, which is Python 2.

[Source](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#specify-python-version)

Comment: Databricks Runtime Version is 6.5 ML And when I run %sh printenv I do not see PYSPARK_PYTHON as an environment variable